# php session 'stops' for no reason

Tags: php, session, vbulletin

I have a vbulletin forum. which is located in `www.myDomain.com/Forum`
I have another in `www.myDomain.com/OtherSite/app`
I want my Forum logged in users to be identified the other site.
The forum's cookies session path is on the main Domain path `/var/www/myDomain`
On my site I use

```
chdir(FORUM_DIR);
include './global.php';
$arr = $vbulletin->userinfo;
```

to get the session. 
**The thing is this - It works**. I get the users data etc...
and then, it **stops working** for no apparent reason after a few page loads.

In my view, a possible reason is that I use the code (listed above) twice in my page load... Could this be it?

***edit:*** 
more code untile the sesion include, As requested.

***edit2:***
thanks @VladTeodorescuI have changed all the include to include_once, but stil the same symptoms, the user data is displayed and then, after 15 mins of using, the session "goes away".. (I have checked the forum site, the user is still logged in there)

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// CONSTS 
//PATHS
define('MAIN_DIR', dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))));
define('APP_NAME', 'GoldSig');
define('CLASS_DIR', MAIN_DIR .'/class');
define('APP_DIR', MAIN_DIR.'/'.APP_NAME.'/app');
define('FORUM_DIR', MAIN_DIR.'/Forum');
define('CHAT_DIR', APP_DIR.'/chat');
//commands and trades tables names
define('T_COMMAND', 'commands');
include_once CLASS_DIR . '/Services/Helper/Files.php';
include_once CLASS_DIR . '/Services/Login/Authorize.php';
if (!Authorize::IsLocalhost()){
    chdir(FORUM_DIR);
    include_once './global.php';
    $arr = $vbulletin->userinfo;
}
```

Comment: 80% of the cases session isn't working because it isn't the first to be included in the page. If that's not it, you need to post more code, maybe its like you say - calling it twice somewhere somehow

Comment: Use **include_once** instead of include. It makes sure you won't include a file twice by mistake, and might very well solve your problem.

Comment: hi @VladTeodorescu, pls see edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to access my domain from `myDomain.com/GoldSig/app`
and the session's data is stored in `www.myDomain.com/GoldSig/app`

I get redirected automatically to `myDomain.com/GoldSig/app` in FF , though..

hard part is over ..